# How to disable prompting to insert second CD while installing a game?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gaming, wine

I’m using Ubuntu 18 and I want to install a game using Wine 5.

Game has two disks, but installation fails to recognize when the second disk is entered.
I manually combined files from both disks and created an ISO file, but the installation is still prompting to insert a second disk.

**How can I disable that prompt and force the installation to just copy everything?**
What file contains that information?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What you want may not be possible. This is usually hard-wired in the installer (which is purpose-built, even when using something like InstallShield).

Comment: I was afraid that was the case…. Is there a way to manually install Windows app on Linux?

Comment: The old trick on Mac was to make separate disk images of each disk & mount them both at once. I've no idea if this would work on any other OS.

Comment: I tried doing that, but Wine refused to recognize both disks. I think this became a Wine question now, I’ll look into in a bit further.